# Is any Payment Gateway exits for overseas customer pay as a dollar for my INR (INDIA) currency based websites

Tags: magento-1.9, price, payment-gateway, internationalization

I need to get my payment from the overseas customer as a dollar value for my INR (india) currency based websites.

> My website Base Currency : INR :: Is any option exists overseas
>   customer pay as a dollar, like INR : 100 payment gateway converted my
>   INR to Dollar as $1.62, and customer pay as $1.62 with shipping price
>   also.

**Is Magento allowed overseas customer pay as dollar for indian website??????????**

Comment: Check Advanced Settings.

Comment: @NikunjVadariya : pls check my question, I updated.

Answer (score 6):

I did a bit of research about it and this is what I understand.

Unfortunately PayPal does not seem to be accepted in India to pay in INR.

You can use PayPal in India if you want to sell your products to overseas customer and in that case you will need to use USD as a currency to accept payments in your store.

Then your bank will take care of the conversion when you withdraw the founds from PayPal.

Customise PayPal in Magento to accept INR will be useless if you get rejected when you send the payment request to PayPal server.

Sources:

- https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-for-Paypal-to-accept-an-online-payment-in-INR-Indian-Rupee
- http://onlinesellingindia.com/paypal-to-sell-online-in-india/
- https://imtips.co/pay-indian-rupees-paypal.html

Comment: What about this one : https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento,  after i installed this extension i get error like  PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your database. open `core_config_data` table `enable` to view all data on one page. Here you can see all your PayPal configs. If you see any PayPal configs with websites or something not like the default in scope field then you have configured PayPal for your current configuration scope.

**Update:**

consider your current config scope is the website. In your `core_config_data` table set value to "**1**" for this `payment/paypal_express/active` for only the other config scopes (website) not the default. Just have a look at the following image. Then check again..

It should be work now..!

Comment: My default country INDIA, is it okay,

Comment: Already my payment/paypal_express/active is enabled like 1,  still not shown front end.

Comment: pls, check my question i updated.

Answer (score 0):

The possible cause is because base currency of your shop is not supported by PayPal.

You can find the Paypal supported currencies in

> app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN', 'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');
```

If your currency code is not in the above list then your currency is not supported by Paypal. And, this is the reason why you are not seeing Paypal payment methods on Checkout page.

**Solution:**

As a workaround, you can add your currency to the `$_supportedCurrencyCodes` array.

For more detail you can visit following link

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-paypal-website-payments-standard-not-displayed/

Comment: after i added country currency code to $_supportedCurrencyCodes, i am getting error like,,    PayPal gateway has rejected the request. Currency is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).